# Form elements order

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have added an labels on the `PictureBox` element, due to a fact that PictureBox is dynamically resized while loading (not very important in this case what does it load)... the problem is that the labels are under the picturebox elements, and arent visible when picturebox is over them.

Is there any solution to set the labels display order to the top available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [BringToFront](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront.aspx) method.

```
label1.BringToFront()
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked, but there is a problem; label1 has now a background color identical to the form background color, instead of the transparent, which was set. Is there a solution for this?